# Diff between exporting function as const and class method

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, commonjs

Whats the diff between these two approaches of exporting and in which situations we go for exporting class and exporting function as const ? Which is ES6+ compatible?

```js
// approach1.js
class Sample1 {
  hello(visitorName) {
    return `hello ${visitorName}`;
  }
}

module.exports = Sample1;
```

And

```js
// approach2.js
const hello = (visitorName) => {
  return `hello ${visitorName}`;
};
module.exports = hello;
```

Test Class

```js
// test.js
const Sample1 = require('./approach1');
const sample2 = require('./approach2');

async function start() {
  const returnValueForApproach1 = (new Sample1()).hello('Name');
  console.log(returnValueForApproach1);

  const returnValueForApproach2 = sample2('Name');
  console.log(returnValueForApproach2);
}
start();
```

Output:
hello Name 
hello Name

Comment: It appears you should do a little reading about the core language concept of when to use a function and when to use a class as that is the core issue here and really has nothing to do with exporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally want to use a class when data gets stored on the *instance* - that is, when you need to refer to `this` in at least one of the methods. For example:

```js
class Sample1 {
  constructor(name) {
    this.visitorName = name;
  }
  hello() {
    return `hello ${this.visitorName}`;
  }
}

const s = new Sample1('foobar');
// ... followed by some code, then
console.log(s.hello());
```

If you don't ever store data on the instance, using a class doesn't make a whole lot of sense, since it adds a bit of extra and somewhat confusing overhead without much reason. JavaScript isn't Java - don't feel like you have to tie everything to a class.

If you just have a *single function*, like in your example, then your second example of

```
const hello = (visitorName) => {
  `hello ${visitorName}`;
};
module.exports = hello;
```

makes the most sense by far; just declare and export the function.

If you had a *collection* of functions not related to instance data, you could export an *object* with those functions, eg:

```
module.exports = {
  fn1() {
    // code
  },
  fn2() {
  }
};
```

All of the code in the question and this answer uses ES6 syntax, so I suppose it's "ES6 compatible".